# How to create a collection in a shared throughput cosmosdb using the Mongo API

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have an Azure CosmosDb database with [database-level throughput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/set-throughput#setting-throughput-on-a-database) provisioned. We're using the MongoDB API against this Cosmos instance. The shared throughput model requires all collections to have a partition key specified, which seems to prevent pretty much any tools from being able to create a collection, other than the Azure Portal or the official Azure Cosmos SDKs. For example, in Robo 3T, attempting to create a collection results in the following error:

> Failed to create collection 'mycollection'.
>
> Error: Shared throughput collection should have a partition key

The same error occurs when attempting to create a collection via mongoose (similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53705816/947986)) or other tooling.

So I guess the operative question boils down to this:
**Is there any way *through the MongoDb API* to pass the desired partitionKey to CosmosDb, so that collection creation will succeed?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Use the `shardCollection` command via db.runCommand(...)

It turns out there *is* a working, if obscure, way to achieve this with the MongoDb wire protocol. You can create a collection with a Cosmos partition key (which conceptually maps to the Mongo Shard Key), by issuing a db-level command to set the sharding key for the not-yet-existing collection:

In a mongo shell:

```
db.runCommand({shardCollection: "myDbName.nameOfCollectionToCreate", 
               key: {nameOfDesiredPartitionKey: "hashed"}})
```

After running this, my ComosDb database (with database-level shared throughput) now contains the new collection with the partition key set appropriately!

I haven't figured out a way to call `runCommand` directly via Mongoose yet, but at least this native/wire protocol approach should work with any of the official MongoDb drivers, so is far more portable than depending on the Azure Cosmos SDK just to create a collection.

Answer (score 1):

Extension commands could be used.

[Create collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-custom-commands#create-collection)

The format of the CreateCollection command is as follows:

```
{
  customAction: "CreateCollection",
  collection: "<Collection Name>",
  shardKey: "<Shard key path>",
  offerThroughput: (int), // Amount of throughput allocated to a specific collection
}
```

JavaScript

```
db.runCommand({customAction: "CreateCollection", collection: "testCollection", shardKey: "sharedKeyName"});
```

Java

```
BasicDBObject testCollection = new BasicDBObject("customAction", "CreateCollection")
                            .append("collection", "testCollection")
                            .append("shardKey", "sharedKeyName");
db.runCommand(testCollection);
```

Comment: Nice, upvoted. I think Extension Commands must not have been a thing when we were first trying to solve this, but they look like the correct approach now.

Comment: Yeah, that's could be the case. Thanks!